# nodelocaldns pod status is CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: kubernetes-pod

FYI, supernoob when it comes to dockers and kubernetes.

Here is my situation, the last two **nodelocaldns** pods are in **CrashLoopBackOff** status.

```
root@test-master:~# kubectl get pods -n kube-system  
NAMEREADY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE  
calico-kube-controllers-64f98644-9l855   1/1     Running            0          6d21h  
calico-node-8w9tz                        1/1     Running            1          6d21h  
calico-node-cvtrx                        1/1     Running            1          6d21h  
calico-node-glp6x                        1/1     Running            1          6d21h  
coredns-74c9d4d795-4z9xt                 1/1     Running            0          6d2h  
coredns-74c9d4d795-cfc7p                 1/1     Running            1          6d2h  
dns-autoscaler-7d95989447-fngw6          1/1     Running            0          6d21h  
kube-apiserver-test-master               1/1     Running            0          6d21h  
kube-controller-manager-test-master      1/1     Running            1          6d21h  
kube-proxy-b7rjs                         1/1     Running            1          6d2h  
kube-proxy-chc94                         1/1     Running            1          6d2h  
kube-proxy-sx5rt                         1/1     Running            0          6d2h  
kube-scheduler-test-master               1/1     Running            1          6d21h  
kubernetes-dashboard-7c547b4c64-9bsgx    1/1     Running            0          6d21h  
nginx-proxy-test-worker1                 1/1     Running            1          6d21h  
nginx-proxy-test-worker2                 1/1     Running            1          6d21h  
nodelocaldns-5mzlc                       1/1     Running            361        6d21h  
nodelocaldns-5qvhc                       0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   1948       6d21h 
nodelocaldns-lmlpr                       0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   1937       6d21h
root@test-master:~#
```

Upon looking at the logs for all three **nodelocaldns** here is what I see:

```
root@test-master:~# kubectl logs **nodelocaldns-5mzlc** -n kube-system  
2020/07/25 09:54:38 2020-07-25T09:54:38.452Z [INFO] Tearing down  
2020/07/25 09:54:38 2020-07-25T09:54:38.553Z [INFO] Setting up networking for node cache  
cluster.local.:53 on 169.254.25.10  
in-addr.arpa.:53 on 169.254.25.10  
ip6.arpa.:53 on 169.254.25.10  
.:53 on 169.254.25.10  
2020-07-25T09:54:38.589Z [INFO] CoreDNS-1.2.6  
2020-07-25T09:54:38.589Z [INFO] linux/amd64, go1.11.10,  
CoreDNS-1.2.6  
linux/amd64, go1.11.10,  
 [INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = cd88e46f28ab8d7e0c280ec4dd60bbb9  
root@test-master:~#  

root@test-master:~# kubectl logs **nodelocaldns-5qvhc** -n kube-system  
2020/07/31 00:08:59 2020-07-31T00:08:59.805Z [INFO] Tearing down  
2020/07/31 00:08:59 2020-07-31T00:08:59.889Z [INFO] Setting up networking for node cache  
listen tcp 169.254.25.10:53: bind: address already in use  

root@test-master:~# kubectl logs **nodelocaldns-lmlpr** -n kube-system  
Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: Authorization error (user=kube-apiserver-kubelet-client, verb=get, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy)
root@test-master:~#
```

Here some initial questions

#1 When I created my ubuntu for my two worker nodes I had it enable a bunch of services,one of them being DNS. Could this be causing my current issue?

#2 Are the last two nodelocaldns pods in **CrashLoopBackOff** status because the first nodelocaldns pod already is using 169.254.25.10?